# Area moment of inertia of trapezium about y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area, polygons

Good day!

As stated in the title, I need to obtain the area moment of inertia, also sometimes called the second moment of area of a trapezium as shown in the figure below, about the y-axis:

[image]

\begin{align}
I_y&=\int x^2 dA \\
   &=\int_a^b x^2y \ dx + \int_b^c x^2y \ dx +\int_c^d x^2y \ dx \\
   &=\int_a^b x^2 \frac{(x-a)}{(b-a)}h \ dx + \int_b^c x^2 h \ dx +\int_c^d x^2\frac{(x-d)}{(c-d)}h \ dx \\
   &=\frac{h(b-a)(3b^2+2ab+a^2)}{12} + \frac{h(c^3-b^3)}{3} + \frac{h(d-c)(d^2+2cd+3c^2)}{12} \\
   &=\frac{h}{12}[(d^3+c^3)-(a^3+b^3)+ cd(c+d) -ab(a+b)] \tag{1} \\
\end{align}

I also referred to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area) wikipedia page which gives that the second moment of area about the y-axis for any simple polygon assumed to have $n$ vertices, numbered in counter-clockwise fashion can be calculated as:
$$I_y =  \frac{1}{12}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {(x_i \ y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} \ y_{i})({x_i}^2 + {x_{i+1}}^2} + x_i \ x_{i+1}) $$
where  $ \ x_{i}, \ y_{i} \ $ are the coordinates of the $i-th$ polygon vertex, for $1\leq i\leq n$. Also, $ \ x_{n+1}, \ y_{n+1} \ $ are assumed to be equal to the coordinates of the first vertex, i.e., $ \ x_{n+1}=x_{1} \ $ and $ \ y_{n+1}=y_{1} \ $. On calculating $I_y$ using above formula for trapezium $ABCD$ as in the figure, **I got back the same answer as (1).**

However a different result shows up [here](https://www.efunda.com/math/areas/IsosTrapezoid.cfm) as:

$$I_y = h \frac {(a+b)(a^2 + 7b^2))} {48} $$

I am stuck as to what the actual output should be, kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something seems off about the last result you linked: For one, it only depends on the 'h', 'a' and 'b' that they have defined- while MoI should indeed depend on at least one other parameter. Your answer is correct afais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram at the link is suspiciously simplified. It is in fact an *isosceles* trapezoid.

[image]

You have calculated the moment for a general trapezoid with four parameters $a,b,c,d$ besides the height – and in two different ways, which should have convinced you enough that your working is correct. To reproduce the isosceles model in the link with only two parameters $a',b'$ and the height the following substitutions must be made:
$$a=0,b=b'/2-a'/2,c=b'/2+a'/2,d=b'$$
Once this is done, simplifying gives the moment of this specialised trapezoid as
$$\frac{h(a'+b')(7b'^2+a'^2)}{48}$$
matching the link.